# xcglogger via cocoapods results in No Such Module

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, xcglogger

caveat: new to cocoapods...
I have a swift xcode project and I'm trying to use the XCGLogger pod, but after adding it to the podfile, (with use_frameworks! ), pod install -- everything looks good:

[image]

but when I put the import XCGLogger in my appdelegate, the compiler tells me No such module: XCGLogger.

```
import UIKit
import Crashlytics
import XCGLogger
```

What could I have done wrong (this time:) ?

thanks!

Comment: How are you importing it? (line of code please)

Comment: @Schemetrical  added imports to question.

Comment: Are you launching the .xcworkspace that was created by cocoapods?

Answer (score 3):

According to: https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger

How to Use

Add the XCGLogger project as a subproject to your project, and add either the iOS or OS X library as a dependancy of your target(s). Under the General tab of your target, add the XCGLogger.framework to the Embedded Binaries.

Then, in each source file:

```
import XCGLogger
```

---

You don't need cocoapods for this. Download the .zip from the link above. Unzip and use the .xcodeproj located in the Library directory for step 1...

1. Add the XCGLogger project as a subproject:
   [image]
2. Add the iOS library as a dependency of your target:
   [image]
3. Under the General tab, add the XCGLogger.framework to the Embedded Binaries:
   [image]

Then...

```
import XCGLogger

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let log = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()

        return true
    }
```

And that's it.